# Magento 2. Use ui form component without a data source

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

- I wish to create a form in admin.
- The purpose of the form is not CRUD.
- Using blocks for creating forms is marked as deprecated in favor of ui_component forms
- Is it possible to use a ui component form without a data source?

Comment: Hello @vitoriodachef, did you find any solution?

Comment: @vedu Please check my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my digging it turns out the data provider is required.

I just implemented a dummy data provider.

```
class Form extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I had to override both methods that work with **$collection** member to avoid errors.

Comment: Does that works still on 2.4.6 ?